# How to show unique value on tcpdf?

Tags: php, tcpdf

Reference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAIbz.png

```
foreach($data as $k=>$v){
//print_r($v);
exit;    
if ($yr != $v['year']) {
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B',9);
$pdf->Cell(25,4, 'Payment Year :',0,0,'L', false,'',0,false,'T','M');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '',9);
$pdf->Cell(10,4, $v['year'],0,1,'L', false,'',0,false,'T','M');

//header
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B',9);
$pdf->Cell(67,4, 'Student',1,0,'C', false,'',0,false,'T','M');
$pdf->Cell(30,4, $v['year'].' Class',1,0,'C', false,'',0,false,'T','M');
$pdf->Cell(47,4, 'Fee',1,0,'C', false,'',0,false,'T','M');
$pdf->Cell(20,4, 'Amount',1,0,'C', false,'',0,false,'T','M');
$pdf->Cell(20,4, 'Total',1,1,'C', false,'',0,false,'T','M');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '',9);       

//$total1 = $total1 + $v['amount'];
$total1 = 0;
 $yr = $v['year'];    
}  

$pdf->MultiCell(67, 4,  $v['student_name'], 1, 'L', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'T', false);
$pdf->MultiCell(30, 4,  $v['class_english_name'], 1, 'L', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'T', false); 
$pdf->MultiCell(47, 4,  $v['fee_group_desc'], 1, 'L', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'T', false);
$pdf->MultiCell(20, 4,  '*'.number_format($v['amount'],2), 1, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'T', false);  
$total1 = $total1 + $v['amount'];
$total2 = $total2 + $v['amount'];
$pdf->MultiCell(20, 4,  number_format($total1,2), 1, 'C', 0, 1, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'T', false);
```

`

Comment: we need more of an explanation than your subject line

Comment: I have same student name on the column, may I know how to make it appear once?

Comment: Any Idea everyone? from data I have a student name with 2 fee, but i wish to display once in tcpdf.

Comment: i guess your in some kind of loop? you need to store the fact that you have used the name, and for the rest of the loop check if you have used the name to determine if you need to display it again

Answer (score 0):

i guess your in some kind of loop? you need to store the fact that you have used the name, and for the rest of the loop check if you have used the name to determine if you need to display it again

outside the loop

```
$name_used=FALSE;//default to false
```

then in your loop

```
if(!$name_used){

$pdf->MultiCell(67, 4,  $v['student_name'], 1, 'L', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 8, 'T', false);
$name_used=TRUE;//after first time through loop make this true, so name not used again    
}else{
//maybe noting, maybe a blank cell
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still can display both 2 student name. Any more suggestion?

Comment: @BullStark edited, forgot to say to place the first line outside the loop